# I need to know if these two sentences are the same in programming

Tags: java, c, syntax, return

I need to know if this:

```
return someBooleanRecursiveMethod(n) || someBooleanRecursiveMethod(n-1);
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (someBooleanRecursiveMethod(n)) 
    return true;
else if (someBooleanRecursiveMethod(n - 1))
    return true;    
return false;
```

if anyone can solve this question fast I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Definitely, Saying `||` is the same as saying OR. Your example does the same thing, it just breaks the two statements apart. They essentially are the same.

For example:

```
if (I like apples) {
    System.out.println("I like a fruit")
} else if (I like bananas) {
    System.out.println("I like a fruit")
}
```

Now, I can clean up these two lines of code in two ways. I could make a switch statement, or, I can use the or operator:

```
if (I like bananas OR I like apples) {
    System.out.println("I like a fruit")
}
```

AKA

```
if (x = 7 || x = 8) {
    System.out.println("Either 7 OR 8")
}
```

The other way I mentioned is called a switch statement. It's slightly more advanced, but it just says,

I have this condition, I have multiple options, do this on this option

```
switch(x) {    
case 6:    
    System.out.println("It is 6");
    break;    
case 7:    
    System.out.println("Either 7 OR 8")
    break;
case 8:
    System.out.println("Either 7 OR 8")
    break;
case 9:    
    System.out.println("It is 9")
    break;
}
```

Basically, in the end you are just doing the same thing. Either you are doing it all in one line of code, or you are splitting it up, and doing it in multiple lines of code. If you want specific outputs for each input, split it up. Otherwise, you're good either way.

Comment: Do you really write code like that? Can you fix a bug when you search for it in this kind of code? Or you rely on the IDE to format it? That seems to be something many programmers do, I personally don't see why not formatting the code would make you faster!

Comment: @iharob Are you talking about my formatting...? I wrote this to help the user, and the code seems readable. I just wrote this code up in stack overflow itself, and not in an IDE.

Comment: I don't think you can ever write code with no formatting at all and then try to make it the right thing to do. I understand you are trying to help and I think that's a good thing, but remember that anyone could follow you and think (code formatting seems irrelevant, professional programmers don't care about that).

Comment: @iharob Thanks for the edit with proper formatting, I appreciate it.

Comment: Don't worry. Just try to care more about that, remeber that programs are read a lot more than written.

Comment: @iharob Great tip. I'll keep that in mind in the future. :-)

Answer (score 0):

They are not equivalent, since someBooleanRecursiveMethod returns a boolean (presumably), the first expression can evaluate to false || false which is false.
The second expression can never return false, unless you specify it.

```
if (someBooleanRecursiveMethod(n))
    return true; 
else if (someBooleanRecursiveMethod(n - 1))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

In this case yes, both expressions are the same, either the method applied to n or n - 1 will return true, otherwise, when both are false returns false(same behaviour as or operator).

Comment: The last `else` is not very relevant to the result. If both conditions are false it will return `false`, otherwise it will return `true`, which is exactly what the `||` operator would do. I understand your confusion, it's OP's fault because of how badly the code was formatted. This is an evidence of the importance of code formatting.

Comment: When he/she first posted the question the code was missing the false return

Comment: No it wasn't. But the code was very hard to understand. Even after someone edited it. The OP never edited the question. BTW, in c or c++ the missing `return` would cause *Undefined Behavior*, I don't know if java would have a default return value.

Comment: @iharob: Early edits don't show in the editing history, so Pedro is probably right. (That grace period is for editing minor typos, but often involves rather major edits that can render quick answers useless.)

Comment: @MOehm I didn't know that. I think Pedro actually did write a good answer, it's the best in this question.